# How get the value of a variable at specified line in a PHP script file passed as argument

Tags: php

I am assigned to write a script TEST.PHP which takes an external PHP file, line number and variable name as its arguments. I have to print the value of the variable at the specified line in the specified file. So far I have done the task the following way

1. After the specified line I simply insert new line `var_dump($var_name); exit(1);`
2. I copy the lines from #1 to the line I have inserted in a separate file
3. I run that file and redirect its output to a log file
4. I read the log file with `tail`

   The whole process is cumbersome. Are there any ideas of making the process simpler and more elegant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Xdebug remote. It allows you to check the values of data structures. Xdebug remote has clients for different platforms. See: https://xdebug.org/docs/remote